# Java JLayeredPane contents flickering on refresh

Tags: java, swing, loops, refresh, flicker

I have a project in NetBeans that uses a layered pane to display overlapping panels by switching between them as necessary. When started, the program displays an intro animation on one of the panels (running on a separate thread), achieved by the following:

```
public class IntroPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Runnable {

private boolean finished;
private int opacity;
private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[3];

public IntroPanel() {
    initComponents();
    labels[0] = jLabel1;
    labels[1] = jLabel2;
    labels[2] = jLabel3;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(JLabel label : labels)
        label.setForeground(new Color(200,200,200,opacity));
}

@Override
public void run(){
    while (!finished) {            
        while (opacity < 255) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
                opacity += 5;
                repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(IntroPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    try {
        repaint();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(IntroPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    while (opacity > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
            opacity -= 5;
            repaint();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IntroPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IntroPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    finished = true;
    }
}
```

The intended effect is to have three JLabels fade in, stay on screen for a moment then fade out. The first two labels contain italics text with a large font size, the third contains small-print. The issues here:

1. The text of the first two labels appears non-italics while fading in or out, only briefly becoming italics while the labels aren't fading.
2. The third label (the small-print, non-italics one) doesn't fade at all, instead "shaking" rapidly up and down during the repaint loops.

I read about how it's a better idea to write my own active rendering method instead of using paintComponent() but replacing paintComponent() with the following:

```
public void render() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    for(JLabel label : labels)
        label.setForeground(new Color(200,200,200,opacity));
    g.dispose();
}
```

does the same flickering. Am I missing something here or looped repaints and layered frames just don't mix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should do none of the code in your paintComponent inside of that method. That should be in another region of your program. paintComponent is for painting only, not for setting state.
2. Your while loops should be replaced by Swing Timer, and this is where the setForground calls should go.
3. You should post a minimal, [complete valid, example, a small program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can compile run and test. Your code does not allow this.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

public class IntroPanel extends JPanel {
   private static final int DELAY_TIME = 5;
   protected static final Color FG_COLOR = Color.blue;
   private List<JLabel> labelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
   private List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<>();

   public IntroPanel() {
      for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
         colorList.add(new Color(0, 0, 255, i));
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
         colorList.add(new Color(0, 0, 255, 255 - i));
      }

      setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

      JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Label 1");
      label1.setFont(label1.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC, 24));
      add(label1);
      labelList.add(label1);
      JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Label 2");
      label2.setFont(label2.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC, 24));
      add(label2);
      labelList.add(label2);
      JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Label 3");
      label3.setFont(label3.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 10));
      add(label3);
      labelList.add(label3);

      new Timer(DELAY_TIME, new ActionListener() {
         private int index = 0;

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (index < colorList.size()) {
               for (JLabel label : labelList) {
                  label.setForeground(colorList.get(index));
               }
               index++;
            } else {
               ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
            }
         }
      }).start();
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      IntroPanel paintEg = new IntroPanel();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("IntroPanel");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(paintEg);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. Did that, no effect.
  2. Did as you said, now there's no repainting whatsoever, not even flickering; it's just a static image.

Comment: D'oh... I didn't put setForeground into the Timer's ActionListener. The disappearing italics issue still persists but I found the source of the problem with the small print: the text doesn't fade because it's encased in <html> tags for automatic word wrapping. I already found the thread talking about it, studying it now.

Comment: Yes, it solved both the flickering and the italics problem. However, now the small-print label's color momentarily becomes dark blue when the fade-in starts and the fade-out ends. I know it's because I do the fading by altering the HTML tag's <font color=''> property on the fly. I only needed HTML for word wrap; is there a text-displaying component that has both horizontal alignment AND word wrap without using HTML? I've been digging through the available components but they either miss one of these or require HTML.

Comment: @amitakartok: yes, a JTextArea can do this if you call the right setters, `setWrapStyleWord(true)` and `setLineWrap(true)`. Also call `setEditable(false)`, `setFocusable(false)`. Consider removing its border as well.

Comment: Tried it, JTextArea does not center the text, nor is there a setter for horizontal alignment.

Comment: Update: it was indeed the HTML that was causing the flickering/coloring problem. I used a JTextPane with custom StyledDocument and it did the trick. Now I only have to figure out why is the JTextPane ignoring setBackground and setting its background to white; tried several solutions posted on various sites, including fiddling with UIManager or using a StyledDocument. None worked.

Comment: Update 2: the JTextPane background color issue was caused by NetBeans defaulting to the Nimbus look & feel. Manually set L&F to Metal, works perfectly. Thanks for the help.